# Excel find rows between two strings and change value in different column for rows between strings

Tags: excel, vba

Not really sure how to go about finding the rows of data between the string [**801 C**] in [**Column B**] and the string [**Nr**] in [**Column A**] then change the value in [**Column C**] for the rows between from [**3**] to [**27**]. I have to reference the data on this sheet on another sheet to be able to graph the data for the L* a* b* for each color standard and the way the standards are stored on the spectrometer there is overlap for the standard ID number between the 700 and 800 color numbers so i have to figure out how to change the value of the standard ID number for the 800 series colors so the graphs only include that data. The standard Id number is the only thing available on each line in the log that ties each line(row) of data to each color. Also need to be able to find multiple instances were both strings may appear in the same sheet multiple times . Any help, ideas and advice will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Log csv]

I did manage with help from here at stackoveverflow to get a batch script to extract the data but can't get it to find but the first instance of both strings and is less than an ideal solution. A macro would be ideal but I am very new to vb scripting and this is beyond my scope of knowledge. Again thank you to anyone who replies to this you are a saint.

Comment: What you are showing has two instances of the "Nr" but the second time the column B string is not "801 C". What is supposed to be done there?

Comment: The "Nr" appears in the log at the top of every block of data when the standard is changed to a different color in the program or if the series is stopped and restarted it will start a new entry for the same color with the Nr at the top of the block. What i need is the "801 C" down to the "Nr' above where the "706 C" data starts this thing has me perplexed.

Comment: The `.Find` method for a range allows you to specify a starting cell. If there are multiple potential occurances of 801 C you basically want to keep looping through that for `.Columns(2)` until it doesn't find anything and use the starting row of the result (.Find returns a range object) to make sure that it finds the correct Nr. If you need actual implementation shown I can do that in a bit.

Comment: An example of implementation would extremely helpful. thank you!

Comment: Need to do a couple thing give me like an hour.

Comment: No problem been trying to figure out this problem for the past couple days a little while longer isn't going to hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't test this so there might be typos but you should be able to get it working:

```
Dim valCell As Range 'store the cell where you find "801 C"
Dim i As Long, first As Long, last As Long 'counter, store rows as you iterate

first = 1 'start at the top
Set valCell = Sheet1.Columns(2).Find("801 C", Sheet1.Cells(first, 2)) 'get the first time you have "801 C", if there are none then this will be Nothing and the While loop condition will fail right away

While (Not valCell Is Nothing)

    first = valCells.Row 'set the first row to the row you found "801 C"
    last = Sheet1.Columns(1).Find("Nr", Sheet1.Cells(first, 1)).Row 'set the last row to the row you found "Nr"

    For i = first To last 'loop through the cells and change the values
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = 27
    Next

Wend
```

Don't forget to change the worksheet reference from Sheet1 to the `.CodeName` for the sheet you are using; that is the name that appears before the parentheses in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim valCell As Range 'store the cell where you find "801 C"
Dim i As Long, first As Long, last As Long 'counter, store rows as you iterate

first = 1 'start at the top
Set valCell = Worksheets("export1").Columns(2).Find("801 C", Worksheets("export1").Cells(first, 2)) 'get the first time you have "801 C", if there are none then this will be Nothing and the While loop condition will fail right away
While (Not valCell Is Nothing)
    If valCell.Row > first Then
        first = valCell.Row 'set the first row to the row you found "801 C"
        last = Worksheets("export1").Columns(1).Find("Nr", Worksheets("export1").Cells(first, 1)).Row 'set the last row to the row you found "Nr"

        For i = first To last 'loop through the cells and change the values
            Worksheets("export1").Cells(i, 3).Value = 27
        Next
        first = last
        Set valCell = Worksheets("export1").Columns(2).Find("801 C", Worksheets("export1").Cells(first, 2)) 'get the next time you have "801 C", if there are none then this will be Nothing and the While loop condition will fail right away8
    Else
        Set valCell = Nothing
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

There got it all sorted "should" find every instance of "801 C" & "Nr" going to leave this here in case it helps someone else out.